# Can hypertext be used with pm3d surface plot in Gnuplot?

Tags: gnuplot

I am trying to read coordinates of various points of the 3D surface (heatmap) created with pm3d.  If I plot just the points in the 3D space with splot command, I can use hypertext to display their X, Y, Z coordinates interactively.  But when I use pm3d command, hypertext seems not working.  Is it possible to use simultaneously hypertext and pm3d?

Comment: Please show some data and some code. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work for you?

```
f(a,b) = sin(a)*cos(b)
set xrange [-pi:pi]; set yrange [-pi:pi]
set samples 21; set isosamples 21

set pm3d 
set pm3d depthorder
splot '++' using 1:2:(f($1,$2)):(sprintf("%.2g %.2g %.2g",$1,$2,f($1,$2))) \
      with labels point lc "#FF000000" hypertext
```

That should give you a pm3d surface with hypertext labels at each vertex.  The  `point lc "#FF000000"` is to make the points transparent so they don't interfere with viewing the surface.

Comment: That looks great, thank you!  I am almost there.  My 3D surface is created from the "matrix" input file, i.e. each line and column in the input file has Z values.  I understand that I have to use the proper "using" option in splot command.  I tried "splot matrix using 1:2:3:($1,$2,$3) with labels point pt 7  hypertext", but it didn't work.  What do I miss?

Comment: The hypertext label (the 4th using specifier) must be a string.   ($1,$2,$3) is not a string.   You can use sprintf to create a string from the numerical values as I showed in the answer.

Comment: My problem is that I use Shell("C:\Program Files\gnuplot\bin\wgnuplot.exe -p -e " + """....splot ....and the rest of your code""")

Comment: Your code works perfect in standalone gnuplot usage.  My problem is that I use Shell("C:\Program Files\gnuplot\bin\wgnuplot.exe -p -e " + """....splot ....and the rest of options...""") function from  VB.NET to run gnuplot and make a 3D surface chart.  When I try to use sprintf, the quotation marks around $%.2g, $%.2g, $%.2g are causing error in MS Visual Studio editor.

Comment: Sorry. I know absolutely nothing about running on Windows or VB.NET.  Maybe ask on a different forum since now the issue is with the command line rather than the program?

Comment: You should be proud of yourself. You showed that there is way to do exactly what I wanted.  Some specifics of my application makes it less straightforward, but doable (I hope).  When I use 1:2:3:($1:$2:$3) , which is incorrect, I still see a hypertext when the mouse pointer moves over the vertices. Though, it shows the constant value. That value is, probably, the first number in the "matrix" input file that I use.  It does not show the X, Y, or Z values at the current location of the pointer. I need to figure out how to update hypertext values based on the current location of the pointer. How?

Comment: Just as in the original example:   `splot $data matrix using 1:2:3:(sprintf("%g %g %g",$1,$2,$3)) with labels point lc "#FF000000" hypertext`

Comment: I will try.  Thanks again.

Comment: I found it.  It is ridiculously simple and stupid.  Instead of  double quotes VB.NET requires single quotes.  I changed it to sprintf('%g %g %g', $1,$2,$3) and went well.  Thank you much again Ethan, you're the great help!

Comment: Great.  If it works then you can mark the answer as accepted so that other people with a similar question can find it. I wasn't sure myself that it would work to begin with. That's certainly not what the hypertext option was designed for.

Comment: I hope I have accepted the answer.  I am new to Stackoverflow.